# org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Complete error is:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It
> could happen in the following cases:
> (1) RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x =>
> rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation
> and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map
> transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
> (2) When a Spark Streaming job recovers from checkpoint, this exception will be hit if a reference to an RDD not defined by the
> streaming job is used in DStream operations. For more information, See
> SPARK-13758.

but I think I didn't use nested rdd transform in my code.

how to solve it?

my scala code:

```
stream.foreachRDD { rdd => {
      val nRDD = rdd.map(item => item.value())
      val oldRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9011/recData/miniApp/mall")
      val top = oldRDD.sortBy(item => {
        val arr = item.split(' ')
        arr(0)
      }, ascending = false).take(200)
      val topRDD = sc.makeRDD(top)
      val unionRDD = topRDD.union(nRDD)
      val validRDD = unionRDD.map(item => {
          val arr = item.split(' ')
          ((arr(1), arr(2)), arr(3).toDouble)
        })
        .reduceByKey((f, s) => {
          if (f > s) f else s
        })
        .distinct()

      val ratings = validRDD.map(item => {
        Rating(item._1._2.toInt, item._1._1.toInt, item._2)
      })
      val rank = 10
      val numIterations = 5
      val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)

      nRDD.map(item => {
        val arr = item.split(' ')
        arr(2)
      }).toDS()
        .distinct()
        .foreach(item=>{
          println("als recommending for user "+item)
          val recommendRes = model.recommendProducts(item.toInt, 10)
          for (elem <- recommendRes) {
            println(elem)
          }
      })
      nRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9011/recData/miniApp/mall")
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're missing a `SparkContext`. I'm guessing that the program fails on this line:

```scala
val oldRDD = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9011/recData/miniApp/mall")
```

The [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#dataframe-and-sql-operations) provides an example of creating a `SparkContext` to use in this situation.

From the docs:

```scala
val stream: DStream[String] = ...

stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  // Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
  val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(rdd.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  // Do things...
}
```

Although you're using `RDD`s instead of `DataFrame`s, the same principles should apply.